# Expression 'navArgs' of type 'YourFragmentArgsName' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Tags: kotlin, arguments

I got the error reported in the title in a Fragment, building a Project in Android Studio with Kotlin, both dependencies and nav_graph.xml file declarations were ok

Answer (score 2):

I solved by manually importing

```
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
```

in the same Fragment.